# Translating JSON values using io.circe

Tags: json, scala

I have a function in scala that translates a value and produces a string.

```
strOut = translate(strIn)
```

Suppose the following JSON object:

```
{
  "id": "c730433b-082c-4984-3d56-855c243265f0",
  "standard": "stda",
  "timestamp": "tsx000",
  "stdparms" : {
    "stdparam1": "a",
    "stdparam2": "b"
  }
}
```

and the following mapping provided by the translation function:

```
"stda" -> "stdb"
"tsx000" -> "tsy000"
"a" -> "f"
"b" -> "g"
```

What is the best way to translate the whole JSON object using the translate function? My goal is to obtain the following result:

```
{
  "id": "c730433b-082c-4984-3d56-855c243265f0",
  "standard": "stdb",
  "timestamp": "tsy000",
  "stdparms" : {
    "stdparam1": "f",
    "stdparam2": "g"
  }
}
```

I must use the `io.circe` library due to project related matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know beforehand which fields you want to translate, or what translations apply to that field, you can use [Cursors](https://circe.github.io/circe/cursors.html) to traverse the JSON tree. Or if the fields themselves are fixed (you always know what fields to expect) [Optics](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html) may require less code.

When you get to the right leaf, you apply the translation.

However, when you don't know what could apply when/where it might be easier to find/replace using string methods.

Note that the JSON you provided as an example is not valid JSON by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have corrected my JSON example. My case is that where the only field known beforehand is the id, which must be preserved.